Can metal get hotter than heat source?
Trying to understand something I have actually witnessed..
My cousin is a welder, and claims that a 400 degree acetylene flame will in time melt steel. He showed me a 400 degree flame, then had a steel plate over the flame for 30 seconds. The plate measured 600 degeees with infrared. How is that possible?

An acetylene flame is 4000 Fahrenheit not 400 Fahrenheit.

Per John Rennie your question is based erroneous information. You should delete it.

Your oven can do 400F routinely.

You are noticing the main measurement error of IR temperature measurements: we don't know the exact emissivity of the object that emits the IR radiation. An object with perfect emissivity has a black body spectrum and the IR thermometer will show the correct temperature. An object with low emissivity will emit less radiation than such a black body and the measured temperature will be too low. Flames and shiny metal surfaces have less then perfect emissivity and they will usually measure too low.

No compressed air no oxygen.. just acetylene. 414* flame temp.

I’ve tried looking for other sources to confirm. He even claims a stick fire under a 1/4” plate of steel in time will melt. That the heat continues to climb past that of the heat sources.

I really appreciate the quick responses as this just threw my whole day off. As far as I know this goes against the law of thermodynamics

All flame temps I can find are acetylene with compressed air 4000* and oxy acetylene

A candle flame burns at about 1000C (1800F). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candle#Temperature IDK about a welding torch, but I've seen an acetylene miner's lamp in action, it it burned hotter than a candle,* so I'd guess that a torch with the oxygen turned off also would burn hotter. [*I mean, the flame was more white, less yellow than a candle flame.]

I’m going with the infrared gun must be inaccurate then. Going off your responses here

I’m going there after work to see this melting in person lol glad I have some info to go with

Since steel melts at around 2500 $^0$F (1370 $^0$C) a 400 ($^0$C or $^0$F) flame would not melt steel.
That aside, it would be impossible for a 400 degrees source to raise the temperature of a material to 600 degrees due to heat transfer alone, as heat only flows naturally from a higher temperature object to a lower temperature object. When the material temperature  reaches the temperature of the source, heat transfer ceases.
The only way the temperature of a material can be higher than the temperature of the heat source is if the material undergoes some type of exothermic chemical reaction as a result of exposure to heat. I'm not aware of any such mechanism involving steel welding (but admittedly, I am no expert on welding), other than something called "exothermic welding" which requires no external source of heat or current. (See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exothermic_welding#:~:text=Exothermic%20welding%2C%20also%20known%20as,source%20of%20heat%20or%20current.)
So it would appear that either the temperature of the steel, or the temperature of the flame, or both, are wrong.
hope this helps.

Yes this definitely helps. Thats all I could come up with is if there was an exothermic reaction between acetylene and carbon steel. Or the infrared gun is not getting an accurate number on the flame

another point to consider is this: once a small area of metal starts heating up, it starts radiating heat away and also conducting heat away too. In order to melt that area, you have to dump in the necessary heat faster than it bleeds away in addition to having a heat source which exceeds the melt temperature. An acetylene torch can do this but a propane torch cannot, for example.
